# Fleet vs Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing

I really confused and didn't know what is the difference between "fleet" and "cluster" in aws. For me, they are all "a bunch of something", and can't distinguish them.

I found that nobody would ask this question since they are on a different level and it's a definition problem that I misunderstand the critical part of them.

We call it an EC2 fleet.
We call it an ECS cluster.
We call it an EKS cluster.

Comment: There aren't particularly solid definitions for these things; in infrastructure terms they're interchangeable. To me, "cluster" implies "clustering" - some interaction/syncronization/replication between a set of instances, whereas a "fleet" implies nothing more than a population of servers.

Comment: @Chumicat Do you mean specific AWS entities such as EC2 Fleet (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-fleet.html) and ECS Cluster (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_clusters.html) or the general usage of the terms?

Comment: @MartinLöper Actually, I want to know both. Since AWS uses a different word to interpretation different service, I want to know the main difference. No matter general or specific on AWS is useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term *ECS cluster* is used for "a logical grouping of tasks or services" or in case of using the EC2 launch-type a "grouping of container instances". [1]
The term *EKS cluster* defines "the Amazon EKS control plane and Amazon EKS worker nodes that are registered with the control plane". [2]
The term *EC2 fleet* is used for "configuration information to launch a fleet—or group—of instances". [3]

These terms are usually used to refer to a **grouping** of resources. The type of resources differs from service to service:

- In EC2, fleets are useful to launch multiple instances at once which are configured with different types (e.g. 1 x t2 and 2 x m5) or purchasing options (e.g. 1 x on-demand and remaining 4 x spot).
- In ECS (with EC2 launch type), we need a way to define which EC2 instances should be used by a particular ECS service (i.e. on which underlying instances the docker containers should run). That group of instances is called a cluster. For the Fargate launch-type, a cluster is provided by AWS automatically, since the underlying infrastructure is launched and managed on-demand.
- In EKS, the term is apparently used to tell apart different EKS environments. It should be consistent with the definition by the official Kubernetes glossary. [4]

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_clusters.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/clusters.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-fleet.html
[4] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-cluster

Answer (score 0):

The sort of assets varies from administration to support: In EC2, armadas are helpful to dispatch various cases without a moment's delay which are arranged with various kinds or buying choices. That gathering of occurrences is known as a bunch.